# Ansible: delegate_to group not working correctly

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

In my dockerized Ansible 2.8 I'm trying to change ssh settings on remote hosts that have been added to inventory dynamically using `add_host`

***playbook.yml***

```
# configure new VMs
- name: Configure new Azure VM
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - az-vm-configure
  tags:
    - az-vm-configure
```

***main.yml***

```
- name: Configure inventory
  include: inventory.yml

- name: Configure sshd
  include: sshd.yml
  delegate_to: '{{ groups.new[0] }}'
```

It works fine when I use following construction: `delegate_to: '{{ groups.new[0] }}'` 
But when I'm trying to implement that for all hosts in group like this:

```
delegate_to: '{{ item }}'
with_items: "{{ groups['new'] }}"
```

my task ignores construction above and tries to execute task on localhost: 
[task execution result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLiC4.png)

Seems like `delegate_to: '{{ item }}'` doesn't work in this case.
Could somebody suggest any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried to place `hosts` in the ***main.yml*** as mentioned above I gave an error
`ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.`
Anyway here's my solution:

***playbook.yml***

```
# configure VM
- name: Add new VM to inventory
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: az-vm-configure
        tasks_from: inventory.yml
  tags:
    - az-vm-configure

- name: Configure new Azure VM
  hosts: new
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: az-vm-configure
        tasks_from: sshd.yml
  tags:
    - az-vm-configure
```

***roles/az-vm-configure/tasks/main.yml***

```
- include_tasks: '{{ tasks }}'
  with_items:
    - inventory.yml
    - sshd.yml
  loop_control:
    loop_var: tasks
```

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"dynamically using add_host"*

```
- name: Configure sshd
  include: sshd.yml
  delegate_to: '{{ groups.new[0] }}'
```

A: It's possible to start next play with the created 'new' group of hosts

```
- hosts: new
  tasks:
    - name: Configure sshd
      include: sshd.yml
```

Comment: ``hosts`` is not a module. See the [Basics](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#basics).